# Can we just "pre-test" the backdoor criterion?

Tags: regression, causality, controlling-for-a-variable, dag, causal-diagram

I am trying to use DAGs to think more carefully about my regression models. I have a question about the "backdoor criterion", as usually seen in the DAG below (we are interested in the effect of $X$ on $Y$). One way to deal with confounding in this case is to include $Z$ in the regression, i.e.~control for it.

But if $Z$ is something that we can measure - for concreteness, in an economic context, $Z$ might be GDP, which often shows up as potential confounder in my DAGs - is it legitimate to first regress $X$ on $Z$ in order to verify that the hypothesised link $Z \to X$ actually exists? If it does, then we go ahead and include $Z$ in the model; if not, the DAG was incorrectly specified, and $Z$ is not in fact a confounder and does not need to be included.

Is this approach reasonable? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, given the DAG, you should only see a correlation between X and Z if there is a direct link between the two, and thus you could test for a correlation directly. These and similar tests are done by all causal discovery algorithms that automatically create the DAG from data, such as the PC algorithm.

However, from the practical perspective of a multiple regression, there are two caveats to this approach:

a) How do you perform the test? A n.s. p-value is not a proof that effect size is zero. Even if the CI is small and overlaps zero, you cannot exclude small confounding effects and thus you have to trade off a small possible bias (from not including a weak confounder) against the improved precision that you gain by having a model with fewer d.f. Plus, there is the issue of post-selection inference, i.e. you need to correct p-values for the tests performed in the model selection.

b) Second, you say that if a variable is not a confounder, it "does not need to be included". I would add to this: for reasons of bias (= causal perspective). However, there are other reasons to include a variable in a multiple regression. Most importantly, if Z is a strong predictor, i.e. if there is a strong link Z->Y, including Z in the regression can reduce the uncertainty on the estimate X->Y, even in the absence of a confounding link Z->X.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent, comprehensive response. (I will wait a day before accepting.)

Comment: Great answer. See also [Pearl (1998)](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2hw5r3tm) "Why There Is No Statistical Test for Confounding, Why Many Think There Is, and Why They Are Almost Right"

Comment: @Noah This is a huge assertion - I've always assumed you confirm confounders after drawing the diagram by testing for correlation (p-values & effect size) between both Z -> X and Z -> Y.

Comment: @RobertF I encourage you to question that assumption :) Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, and any relationship you study can be due to confounding unless you already know the confounders to adjust for. Also, variables can be correlated with the treatment and outcome and not be confounders. Pearl explains it all. Of I say that it's much greater assertion to claim you can learn a causal graph from data and assumptions about temporal ordering alone, which is what your method implicitly suggests.

Comment: @Noah Right, I understand there are all sorts of contingencies when performing empirical tests. Although it's not unreasonable to claim you've accounted for all of the important variables & their relationships (eg, after consulting with subject matter experts in the field). But X -> Y shutting down(?) the confounder test for Z -> Y is a neat illustration of the usefulness of causal diagrams. I'm surprised it's not mentioned in the literature more often.

Comment: I'm not familiar with automated causal diagram builders like the PC algorithm. Are they reliable?

Comment: @RobertF, see e.g. Glymour et al., 2019 Review of Causal Discovery Methods Based on Graphical Models https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2019.00524/full ... as for any dichotomous decision, they have to trade off type I / II error rates, so of course they will not always generate the correct graph.

Comment: @FlorianHartig Thank you Florian - my worry with these algorithms is they can't separate correlation from causation so you'll see a large number of incorrect causal relationships. If three variables are all correlated with each other, can you deduce the true location, direction, and magnitude of the causal arrows?

Comment: @RobertF - the whole point of these algorithms is to separate correlation from causation. You have to read the literature, but the tldr is: it's possible up to a point!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in order to confirm a confounding relationship you may perform a regression (or Chi-squared test or other suitable model) of $Z$ on $X$ and $Z$ on $Y$. This is exactly what I'm doing right now for a difference-in-differences healthcare analysis.

There may be confounders or colliders, measured or unmeasured, associated with $Z$ and $X$ or $Z$ and $Y$ that can cloud the true causal relationship between the variables. Therefore, it's important to flesh out the DAG prior to performing regression tests.

Comment: Thank you, @Robert! Would you happen to have a reference for this "confounder testing"?

Comment: Robert, you can test z ~ x but I do not see how you could test z ~ y because there is a mediator path z ~ x ~ y that could cause a correlation in z ~ y even in the absence of a direct link. You would have to condition on X but then you might as well fit the entire DAG.

Comment: Broadly speaking, you would be engaging in model selection here, which is a task with nontrivial issues - pretesting effects etc.

Comment: @Anthony Yes, Daw & Hatfield (2018) outlines empirical tests for confirming the existence of confounders, including a diagram: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326071994_Matching_and_Regression_to_the_Mean_in_Difference-in-Differences_Analysis

Comment: @FlorianHartig Wow, this is the first time I've read you can't test Z -> Y due to mediation effects, strange this isn't mentioned in the literature.

Comment: @FlorianHartig Will have to think on this some more - if X has a very weak causal relationship with Y, but Z -> X and Z -> Y are stronger there will be less information "leaking through" to Y.

Comment: @RoberF - sure, but in principle, you can see Z ~ Y even if there is no Z -> Y, and the reverse, so it's not a reliable test.